# iText7 in Azure Powershell Runbook - how to save changes made to a PDF

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, itext, itext7

I have a solution I am trying to implement which involves taking a PDF from a Sharepoint Online folder, modifying it, and then saving the output to another Sharepoint Online folder. It has to be done in an Azure Runbook running powershell 7.2.

I'm probably not explaining this properly, but my problem is that the <PDFWriter> doesn't seem to be able to save to the Sharepoint.

I spent too much time figuring out that the input needed to be as a MemoryStream download from Sharepoint - but I seem stuck figuring out how to get the output back into Sharepoint...

Here is what currently works:

```
#GET PACKAGE FOR ITEXT7
initialiseitext7

#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX/"
$ListName= "Documents partages"
   
#Connect to SharePoint Online site
$pnpconnection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ManagedIdentity  -ReturnConnection

$pnpSharedDocs =Get-PnPFolder -Url "/sites/XXXX/Documents partages/inputPDF" -connection 

$pdfloc1 = "/Documents partages/InputPDF/testPDF.pdf"

#get Stream of PDF from sharepoint site
$pnpPDFfile =Get-PnPFile -Url $pdfloc1 -AsMemoryStream -connection $pnpconnection

$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pnpPDFfile)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$pdf.AddNewPage()
$pdf.AddNewPage()
$pdf.AddNewPage()


$totalPages = $pdf.GetNumberOfPages()
$pdf.Close()

Write-Output "Number of pages: $($totalPages)"
```

The above works in that the $totalpages will return 4, BUT the sharepoint PDF that went into the PdfWriter doesn't save as a pdf with 4 pages. As though it was read only.

Ultimately, I'd like to have an example where a PDF is correctly saved to **any other sharepoint folder**...

I am also very much welcoming of any alternative solutions as long as they remain in an Azure Runbook, or any solution where the code is all Powershell.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the input. The folder isn't sync'd to anything. What do you mean <run as server CPU app' ? I understand the local download part, but that is the part I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I will see what I can do about this limitation...